# Making images appear AND other images disappear with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, visible, invisible

I am having some trouble with my webpage. I researched on this topic for 30 minutes straight and still found no direct answer.

If I click button1:

- image1 visible
- image2 invisible
- image3 invisible

If I click button2:

- image1 invisible
- image2 visible
- image3 invisible

If I click button3:

- image1 invisible
- image2 invisible
- image3 visible

Here is my Javascript:

```
function rock(){
document.getElementById('image1').style.display = 'block';
}
document.getElementById('image2').style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('image3').style.display = 'none';
}

function paper(){
document.getElementById('image1').style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('image2').style.display = 'block';
}
document.getElementById('image3').style.display = 'none';
}

function scissors(){
document.getElementById('image1').style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('image2').style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('image3').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<button id="rock" onclick="rock()">Rock</button>
<button id="paper" onclick="paper()">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors" onclick="scissors()">Scissors</button>
```

Comment: If you want us to tell you what's wrong with what you've tried, you have to post the code. We're not going to just write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Give id to all buttons
2. Give id to all images
3. [Add event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) 
   to each button
4. Hide an image like this

   document.getElementById("id-of-the-image").style.display = "none";
5. Show an image like this

   document.getElementById("id-of-the-image").style.display = "inline-block";

**Your code (with correction)**

```
function rock(){
    document.getElementById('image1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('image2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('image3').style.display = 'none';
}

function paper(){
    document.getElementById('image1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('image2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('image3').style.display = 'none';
}

function scissors(){
    document.getElementById('image1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('image2').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('image3').style.display = 'block';
}
```

**An optimized version of your code**

```
function showImage(imageId) {
    document.getElementById(imageId).style.display = 'block';
}
function hideImage() {
    document.getElementById(imageId).style.display = 'none';
}


function rock(){
    showImage('image1');
    hideImage('image2');
    hideImage('image3');
}

function paper(){
    hideImage('image1');
    showImage('image2');
    hideImage('image3');
}

function scissors(){
    hideImage('image1');
    hideImage('image2');
    showImage('image3');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply use this to hide it:

```
document.getElementById("thingid").style.visibility="hidden";
```

use this to show it:

```
document.getElementById("thingid").style.visibility="visible";
```

Very nice tutorial on this page:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

2ndary suggestion: you can use jquery to create nice transition effects